# How to connect ,query and insert data to MYSQL database from android app via Amazon RDS service

Tags: java, android, mysql, amazon-rds

I am creating an android application which has login and registration functionalities.I want my db to be resided in cloud instead of local i.e SQL lite.

Below steps I followed

- Step 1) I chose Amozon RDS free-tier and followed documentation to
  create a db instance .I created it and got the end point url as well.
- Step 2)I gave the host name,password and port created from AWS RDS in mysql work bench and
  clicked on test connection .It showed success full connection.

Now my question is how I can insert/retrieve data from android to mysql directly using RDS since RDS does not provide any option to insert.
If there! please let me know.

Does AWS RDS service can be exposed as a REST URL to insert the data ?

If any open source freeware dbs that are hosted in cloud which
supports android app available then that also would be helpful.

I researched with Firebase but stuck with documentation.

Since I wanted to do a demo I can go with free-tier as of now.

Comment: Removed few sentences.Kindly accept this question without putting on hold

Comment: Why? It's still a *broad* question. It's too broad because it asks for a magic solution and shows lack of experience with basics, especially mobile and databases. AWS RDS is a **database**. Exposing a database to the public internet isn't exactly smart. Amazon isn't going to expose it like this. *You* have to write a REST service. Or use Amazon's services for mobile applications. In any case, this is a very broad subject that requieres an entire tutorial to answer

Comment: The [Amazon Mobile SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdk/) is a good place to start

Comment: Thanks Knavois.I am looking to dynamo db now .But all these are paid ones.But any free-tier services are there available in market which exposes api

Comment: These are AWS licensing, not programming questions. AWS is *not* free. AWS offers both free tiers for some services. Others have a free tier for a one year period. At some point though you'll have to pay. If you can't pay for a service now, you'll have to build its equivalent and host it in a free VM or other service

Comment: Yes I do agree with you some services in AWS are free-tier for some days.Apart from AWS any  other services which you are aware of.Since I am creating a POC I cannot go with paid one.Later once the code is stabilized I can afford to go with this.

Comment: That's still off-topic for SO. If you can't even afford to pay $1-$2 for a POC, don't even look at expensive services like RDS. Use another service that charges by transaction or traffic